# How to navigate from one fragment created in one Navigation graph to another fragment situated in another Navigation Graph?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack, android-navigation

I have created an **MainActivity** which has a fragment **HelloFragment** and a Navigation Graph **nav_graph**.
And I also have another Activity **WhyActivity** which has a fragment **WhyFragment** and a Navigation Graph **nav1**. So I want to navigate from **HelloFragment** to **WhyFragment**, Both activities contain only one fragment each. I have created the following code but I am not sure how am I suppose to approach it. I have created both of the fragment in separate navigation graph but I want go from one to another. Following is my code.

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.multiplenavgraph

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The fragment HelloFragment.kt

```
package com.example.multiplenavgraph

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup



class HelloFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hello, container, false)
    }
    
    }
```

fragment_hello.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HelloFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Hello" />

</FrameLayout>
```

This is the Navigation Graph for the **nav_graph.xml** where HelloFragment is situated.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/helloFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/helloFragment"
        android:name="com.example.multiplenavgraph.HelloFragment"
        android:label="fragment_hello"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_hello" />
</navigation>
```

This is the code for the WhyActivity.kt

```
 package com.example.multiplenavgraph

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class WhyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_why)
    }
}
```

Below is the code for activity_why.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WhyActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Following is the code for WhyFragment.kt

```
package com.example.multiplenavgraph

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup

class WhyFragment : Fragment() {
   
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_why, container, false)
    }
}
```

Following is fragment.xml code for fragment_why.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WhyFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="why" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Below is the code for Navigation graph where my Fragment WhyFragment.kt is situated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav1"
    app:startDestination="@id/whyFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/whyFragment"
        android:name="com.example.multiplenavgraph.WhyFragment"
        android:label="fragment_why"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_why" />
</navigation>
```

So, I want to go from Fragment **HelloFragment** to **WhyFragment** ?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no special reason for having two Activities, why not just merge those NavGraphs?

Nonetheless, the answer to your question as it stands is - you don't/can't.

`Navigation` works with `Fragment`s, not `Activity`-ies.

Your current structure is something like this

```
MainActivity - nav_graph - HelloFragment
WhyActivity - nav - WhyFragment
```

If you want to transition from `MainActivity` to `WhyFragment`, you would have to start `WhyActivity` - but as you said, each activity has one `Fragment` so it kinda defeats the whole purpose.

You *can* include the `nav` in the `nav_graph` as a [nested-graph](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/design/nested-graphs).

```
<include app:graph="@navigation/nav" />
```

which will allow you to move from `HelloFragment` to `WhyFragment` but it will be within the `MainActivity` and create something like this:

```
MainActivity - nav_graph - HelloFragment
                         - nav - WhyFragment
```

but it is needlessly complicated.

I think what you are actually looking for is basically this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/helloFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/helloFragment"
        android:name="com.example.multiplenavgraph.HelloFragment"
        android:label="fragment_hello"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_hello">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_hello_to_why"
            app:destination="@id/whyFragment"/>

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/whyFragment"
        android:name="com.example.multiplenavgraph.WhyFragment"
        android:label="fragment_why"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_why" />
</navigation>
```

and to move to the `WhyFragment` call

```
findNavController().navigate(HelloFragmentDirections.actionHelloToWhy())
```

Comment: the reason why I want to create two activities is, currently in my project, there is only one actvity and one nav graph where I have all the fragments and eventually there comes a Fragment A where I want to display tabLayout and which has three tabs [Eaasy, medium and hard] and here Fragment A will be default for Easy and then I want to create two seperate fragments medium and hard. But when I try to implement in TabLayout and ViewPager2 in Activity xml file, it doesn't give the TabLayout so I thought to make seperate Nav graph and put the medium and hard fragments there ...